# Calculate cumulative percentage without sorting data

Tags: excel, excel-2010

sorry for my English but I'm not a native speaker.

I wandered to find a way to do this operation but could not find any answer neither here nor on other online sources, I apologize in advance in case it was a trivial question.

Let's assume I had a single column of percentages: when summed, they give 100%.

> 5%
>
> 70%
>
> 3%
>
> 7%
>
> 2%
>
> 13%

I don't want to sort the data and then find the relative cumulative percentage; I would like to find the number of percentages starting from the bottom value which must be summed in order to reach or trespass the 10% threshold. In this case, it would be 3 as the sum of 2% + 3% + 5%.

As I said, I have searched online but I fail spectacularly when I try to solve this by myself: one example is a similar question answered here (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/642660-how-to-find-number-of-rows-that-meets-cumulative-percentage-critieria.html) but even though I downloaded the sample and copied the solution I still  can't figure out how to continue. My Excel is in another language so this could be the problem of the copy/paste of the various formulas but the answer provided is a bit outdated and I assumed there would be a more precise way to address this issue.

Thanks in advance for your precious insights.

Comment: There might be alternate options if you're not strictly using Excel. One could then use programming libraries that kind of do the work for you. Then one just needs to port such a library to VBA (or in .NET/C++ to compile an Excel/Office plugin). Too bad likely no one has done such work already though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't come up with a single formula / generic solution, but if the number of percentage values you're going to have is "reasonable", I'd suggest setting up a second sheet similar to the following:

[image]

The counter column is just numbers from 1 to the number of entries you have, and can have a formula similar to:

```
=ROW()-1
```

The second column formula is:

```
=SMALL(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6,A2)
```

Third column formula:

```
=SUM(B$2:B2)
```

The answer formula then is:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(0.1,$C$2:$C$7,0),1+MATCH(0.1,$C$2:$C$7,1))
```

Comment: I must say it works, even though I have multiple sheets and columns so this could prove to be a bit complex to manage on my file. Thanks for sharing!